# Cannot find System DSN in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, dsn

I have created System DSNs to a MySQL and Oracle database and I have been able to use these DSNs to create linked servers in my SQL Server database and all is working fine.

However, I am trying to create a report in BIDS 2008 / Reporting Services 2008 R2 and I am unable to get these system DSNs. When I try creating a data source, I select Type as ODBC, click Edit, my System DSNs on that same machine aren't displayed.

I will be very grateful for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 64-bit machine? If so, be aware that on a 64-bit machine there are **TWO** ODBC Data Source Administrators, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit drivers. If you create a System DSN in either one, it is not visible in the other.

The 64-bit version is usually in C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe

The 32-bit version is usually in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

I'm not sure which version Reporting Services is looking for but try opening both versions up and re-creating your DSN in the one where it's missing (assuming there are both 32-bit and 64-bit drivers for your data source).